# exchange 2007 for loop - csv

Tags: powershell

I have a list of about 200 users. I would like the display name, total item size and last log on attribute for each user in a CSV, but I can't figure out how to append the information to the CSV file.

Now I know I need to use `format-csv` to get it into a csv file of course, but with Server 2008 and Exchange 2007 there is no append option.

I presume I need to create some kind of array and add the output of each foreach loop to the variable, and then export to a CSV after all iterations of the loop are complete.

This is where I am stuck, I am really not sure if, this is the correct approach or where to start.

```
$users = get-content -path C:\x\x\x
foreach ($user in $users) {
   get-mailbox $user | get-mailboxstatistics |
   select displayname,lastlogontime,`
   @{n="Total Size (MB)";e={$_.totalitemsize.value.ToMB()}}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `+=` to add data to an array and then export that array to CSV:

```
$users = get-content -path C:\folder\users.txt
$information = @()

foreach ($user in $users) {
   $information += get-mailbox $user | get-mailboxstatistics | select displayname,lastlogontime,@{n="Total Size (MB)";e={$_.totalitemsize.value.ToMB()}}
}
$information | Export-CSV C:\folder\mailbox_info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```